# iphone gmail code examples

Tags: ios4

I want to display login window and then type login and password credencial it will open the account. So i tried but it shows error like 
**/81: error: 'didReceiveMemoryWarning' undeclared (first use in this function)**
**:81: error: expected ';' before '{' token**
**100: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input**

and i posted below the code please help 
*Thanks in advance*

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Password1ViewController : UIViewController {

UITextField *textfieldName;
UITextField *textfieldPassword;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textfieldName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textfieldPassword;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "Password1ViewController.h"

@implementation Password1ViewController

@synthesize textfieldName;
@synthesize textfieldPassword;

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertview cancelButtonIndex])
    {

        NSLog(@"Name: %@", textfieldName.text);
        NSlog(@"Name: %@", textfieldPassword.text);
    }
}

-(void) someMethod
{
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Login" message:@""                                            delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Submit",nil];

    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"User Name"];
    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Password"];

    textfieldName = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textfieldName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    textfieldName.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textfieldName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    textfieldPassword = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
    textfieldPassword.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textfieldPassword.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    textfieldPassword.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textfieldPassword.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textfieldPassword.secureTextEntry = YES;

    [alert show];
}
/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [textfieldName release];
    [textfieldPassword release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: use four spaces before each code line and further four spaces if writing code inside a loop and so on. You can always have the preview of your code while you are writing down under.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a closing brace which I corrected in my edit. So, try now with the edited code.